# Django Open and View a PDF(stored in AWS) in a new Tab

Tags: django, pdf

I have a model that stores a PDF file. On the DetailView of that Model I would like to have a link to view the PDF in a new tab. There are similar questions on here that I've used to get this far, but it looks like they're for local PDFs. My PDFs are stored as Media on AWS.

This is what I have right now:

plans/models.py

```
class PlanSet(PlanModel):
    ...

class PlanSetPDF(models.Model):
    planset = models.ForeignKey(PlanSet)
    PDF = models.FileField(upload_to='planPDFs')
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True)
```

plans/views.py

```
class PlanSetDetailView(DetailView):

    model = PlanSet
    template_name = "plan_detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PlanSetDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['now'] = timezone.now()
        return context

def view_pdf(request, pk):
    pdf = get_object_or_404(PlanSetPDF, pk=pk)
    image_data = open(pdf.PDF.url, "rb").read()
    return HttpResponse(image_data, contenttype='application/pdf')
```

plans/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', plan_detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/pdf/$', view_pdf, name='view_pdf'),
]
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^plans/', include(plan_sets.urls, namespace='plans')),
```

template:

```
{% for pdf in object.plansetpdf_set.all %}
  <a href="{% url 'plans:view_pdf' pdf.pk %}">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file" aria-hidden="true"></span>PDF</a>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm recieving a builtin.OSError:[Errno 22] Invalid Argument: 'https://link_to_PDF_file_on_amazon'

It looks like Python can't open the file. I've looked around and I can't find any answers. Can one of you show me where I'm going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I can't see the point of your `view_pdf` view at all. All it does is open the PDF via its URL, download it, and then re-send it to the browser. Why bother? You should just link directly to the PDF's url; and when you do so you can tell the browser to open it in a new tab:

```
<a href="{{ pdf.PDF.url }}" target="_new">
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, after posting I did notice that if I just copy and paste the link into the browser it works, however, the link includes my AWS Signature and AWS AccessKeyId, is there a potential security risk there?